# Temporary namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

Is there any way to temporary use a namespace ?
I'm using a library to create forms and it uses namespaces, the problem is that I usually want to create a form in the middle of a page, which is thus in the global namespace. Then if I want to call any function of this library I have to prefix everything with Namespace\

Isn't there any way in PHP to do something like this :

```
Blabla global namespace
strlen('test'); // 4

namespace Namespace
{
    test();
}

More global PHP
```

And have it refer to Namespace\test ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

> ```
> <?php
> namespace foo;
> use My\Full\Classname as Another;
>
> // this is the same as use My\Full\NSname as NSname
> use My\Full\NSname;
>
> // importing a global class
> use ArrayObject;
>
> $obj = new namespace\Another; // instantiates object of class foo\Another
> $obj = new Another; // instantiates object of class My\Full\Classname
> NSname\subns\func(); // calls function My\Full\NSname\subns\func
> $a = new ArrayObject(array(1)); // instantiates object of class ArrayObject
> // without the "use ArrayObject" we would instantiate an object of class foo\ArrayObject
> ?>
> ```

This is about the closest you can get - there's no way to change the default namespace temporarily.

Comment: Ok that might be good enough. Quick question : I'm using a set of classes in my global namespace, imported via autoloader. Now, if I declare them all in the begining with use, but they still are loaded when called, will it change anything performance-wise ?

Comment: they'll be loaded via the use statements, not when they are called.  It shouldn't change anything performance wise, just another file getting included by your autoloader.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, and while the accepted answer answers the question as it was asked, I feel like what the OP is really asking is "Can I use items in the global namespace from another namespace. The answer here is a clear and simple yes.

Imagine two classes (one in the global namespace, another in its own:

`ClassInGlobal.php`

```
<?php
class ClassInGlobal
{
    public static function doStuff()
    {
        echo 'I do some stuff';
    }
}
```

`ClassInNamespace.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Classes;

class ClassInNamespace
{
    public function callDoStuff()
    {
        \ClassInGlobal::doStuff();
    }
}
```

The above executes fine. All that is required is a leading slash to specify the fully qualified global namespace. Additionally, you could add a `use ClassInGlobal` declaration right after the namespace declaration and omit the leading slash.

This might translate into the original question by abstracting the namespaced functions into a class Then you could modify the OP's code slightly to acheive this:

```
require './Namespace/Utilities.php';

Blabla global namespace
strlen('test'); // 4

\Namespace\Utilities::test();

More global PHP
```

Hope that helps someone coming here looking for that.